# Transfer keys from a 2D array to fill a 1D array

Tags: php, arrays

PHP has plenty of useful functions and Im wondering if Im overlooking one that has already been built.

Lets say you have an array such as:

```
$first_array = array("Name"=>"Angela", "Age"=>24);
```

and you wanted to grab the keys from the first array to create a second array (which could then be pushed into a third array). So you need to create:

```
$second_array = array("Name", "Age");
```

Is there a way to achieve this result without this loop?:

```
foreach($first_array as $k=>$v){
    array_push($second_array, $k);
}
```

Comment: [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
array_keys($first_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_keys($first_array)` to get the array of all the keys in the `$first_array`